# Unattended upgrades log

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, log-files, ubuntu-16.04

I currently have unattended upgrades on two different servers with Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 respectively.

While in Ubuntu 16.04 the logs are saved in /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

In Ubuntu 14.04 are saved as
/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg_yyyy_mm_dd_hh:mm:ss.log

After looking for how to change this log format so that in Ubuntu 14.04 is only unattended-upgrades.log I have not found anything.

Does anyone know how I can change the format of the log?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on Ubuntu 14.04 unless you install a newer version of the unattended-upgrade package (which, as of today, doesn't exist on the official Ubuntu repositories).  The logging behavior, and its configuration, has been changed with version 0.83.  Trusty (Ubuntu 14) only has version 0.82.1.

You can see the discussion about this change in the [Debian bug report #759693](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=759693)